# Is an 18 month OIS a bullet?

Tags: ois, sofr

I have been looking at SOFR/fixed swaps.  On Bloomberg I found USOSFR1F which is the 18 month tenor on the SOFR OIS curve.

My understanding is that SOFR OIS pays annually.  When bootstrapping to get a zero curve, should I treat this instrument as a bullet?

Comment: Did you try "DES <Go>"?

Comment: Yes.  DES gives a generic description attributed to all the curve members.  Has nothing specific regarding treatment of the 18 mo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWPM  is your friend when it comes to coupon schedules. If I recall correctly, 18m SOFR pays at 12 months and 18 months.