# No. of payments in 15/18/21 month ESTR OIS

Tags: swaps, bootstrapping, ois, ois-swaps

I want to construct a zero-curve from EUR OIS rates (IR swaps with ESTR as the floating rate).


For bootstrapping, some of the contracts I use have maturities of 15, 18 and 21 months (RIC: *EUREST15M=* etc.). How many payments do these contracts have, and when do they occur?


I found this similar thread, but can't find anything for the EUR market: [Is an 18 month OIS a bullet?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/68942/is-an-18-month-ois-a-bullet)

Answer (score 1):

For ESTR OIS market convention is that there is a front stub period i.e. the first period is shorther, the next one is always 12 months. Therefore:

1. 15M OIS -> 3M payment + 12M payment,
2. 18M OIS -> 6M payment + 12M payment,
3. 21M OIs -> 9M payment + 12M payment.

Hope that helps.